# Convert hour to 12 hr format after extracting 'hour' using DatePart(hour,Datetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssms-2012

I have a small issue I'm trying to resolve. I currently have a datetime field in my database. What I am doing already is extracting the HOUR, Minute and AM/PM part from the date since I have to populate each value into a seperate field.

This is what the query looks like:

```
Select 'Hour'=(SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, Date1)), 
'Minute'=(SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, Date1)), 
'PM'= (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Date1) > 11 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'AM' END)
from tblA
```

So here I am able to have the 3 values. However the Issue I have is the HOUR part, by default is displayed in a 24 hour format. Is there any way to convert it to 12 hour format?

I am aware that I can use the format = 100 to convert time to 12HR format  like so:

```
select convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),100)
```

However when I apply this to just the 'HOUR' value, it doesn't change the format. Is there another way to accomplish this?

To clarify, if the datetime value in my table is : `2018-11-22 14:30:00.000`
I am hoping to get a result that looks like this:

```
Hour      Minute       PM
2         30           PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator.

```
CASE
  WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, Date1) % 12 = 0 THEN
    12
  ELSE
    DATEPART(HOUR, Date1) % 12
END
```

Comment: Make sense, I just figured it out by doing a CASE WHEN DatePart(Hour,Date1) > 12 then DatePart(Hour,Date1) - 12 ELSE DatePart(Hour,Date1) END. Yours is shorter

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
 Declare

    @Date1 dateTime;
    Set @Date1 ='2018-11-22 14:30:00.000';

     Select 'Hour'= Case When (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, @Date1)) >12 Then (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, @Date1))-12 Else (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, @Date1)) End, 
    'Minute'=(SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, @Date1)), 
    'PM'= (CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, @Date1) > 11 THEN 'PM' ELSE 'AM' END)
```

Comment: Thanks. but see my comment under the first answer.